# Why is check_password_hash always returning False in this login view?

Tags: python, hash, flask

I have a user model with functions to set and check a password using Werkzeug's `set_password_hash` and `check_password_hash` functions.

models.py

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(15), unique = True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(15))
    tasks = db.relationship('Task', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.set_password(password)

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password, password)
```

login.py

```
def post(self): 
    username = flask.request.form['username']
    passwd = flask.request.form['passwd']
    user = User.query.filter_by(username = username).first()
    flask.flash(user.check_password(user.password))
    if user and user.check_password(user.password):
        flask.session['username'] = username
    else:
        flask.flash("User doesn't exist or password is inccorect.")
        return flask.render_template('login.html')
    return flask.render_template('index.html')
```

The flashed result of `check_password` is always "False".  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've defined `User.password` to have a length of 15, but the password hash is longer than 15 characters.  So when you go to compare it later, it will not be the same value, it will be truncated.

The solution is to either define a longer length to accommodate the length of the hash, or use a database that doesn't care about length (PostgreSQL, SQLite) and don't set a length for the column at all (this is preferable).

```
password = db.Column(db.String)  # no length
# or
password = db.Column(db.String(255))  # some longer length
```

---

There's also a second problem: you're calling `check_password` with the stored hash, not with the user input.

```
# wrong
user.check_password(user.password)
# should be
user.check_password(passwd)
```

---

The following is a small example that demonstrates the password working correctly.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
session = Session(engine)
Base = declarative_base(engine)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = sa.Column('password', sa.String)

    def set_password(self, secret):
        self.password = generate_password_hash(secret)

    def check_password(self, secret):
        return check_password_hash(self.password, secret)

Base.metadata.create_all()

u = User(username='davidism')
u.set_password('cabbage')
session.add(u)
session.commit()

u = session.query(User).filter_by(username='davidism').one()
print(u.password)
# pbkdf2:sha1:1000$w9jx4Egp$b420d784ac6ad0575e4a9a908bb4679826e56f5f
print(u.check_password('cabbage'))
# True
```