# Flask BCrypt check_password_hash return False after saving via MongoEngine

Tags: mongodb, flask, mongoengine, bcrypt

I run into a weird situation, which is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830262/why-is-check-password-hash-always-returning-false-in-this-login-view) . This is my model:

```
class User(db.Document):
    email = db.EmailField(required=True, unique=True)
    username = db.StringField(max_length=50, required=True, unique=True )
    password = db.StringField(required=True)
    first_name = db.StringField(max_length=100, required=False)
    last_name = db.StringField(max_length=100, required=False)
    role = db.IntField(required = True, choices = role_choices, default = 5)
    status = db.IntField(required = True, choices = status_choices, default = 1)
    last_login = db.DateTimeField(required=False)

    @property
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return True

    @property
    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        username = kwargs.pop('username', None)
        password = kwargs.pop('password', None)
        email = kwargs.pop('email', None)

        super(User, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.username = username
        self.set_password(password)
        self.email = email

    meta = {
        'allow_inheritance': False,
        'indexes': ['-username'],
        'ordering': ['-username']
    }

    def check_password(self, password):
        return bcrypt.check_password_hash(self.password, password)
```

When I first create an instance of this User class, everything works as expected:

```
an = User(username="annguyen", first_name="An", last_name="Nguyen", password="janet78", email="an@gmail.com")
>>> an.password
'$2b$12$Ho9Q0/n4FPERytHKxA3szu8gzRZE4J9FxuZots8FFxJUKP6ULmqpe'
>>> an.save()
<User: annguyen>
>>> len(an.password)
60
>>> an.check_password('janet78')
True
```

However, when I retrieve this user from the database, the check_password method always return False.

```
>>> an_new = User.objects.get(username='annguyen')
>>> an_new.password
'$2b$12$j9VfNiySMKN19cYIEjuAseiamREUmGbB2ZFM4faoLJySB6uZfaCj2'
>>> len(an.password)
60
>>> len(an_new.password)
60
>>> an_new.check_password('janet78')
False
```

It is very clear that the password retrieved from the database is very different from what it was before being saved to the database, and therefore it always returns False. I spent a whole day trying to figure out what's wrong but couldn't come up with any clue. Can someone help point out how I can fix it.

I am developing on Windows 10 with Python 2.7, Flask 0.10.1, MongoDB 3.2, flask-mongoengine==0.7.5, mongoengine==0.10.6

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any idea? I found that the only problem is the way MongoEngine saves document to the database. It changes the value of the password hash. I changed from Bcrypt to werkzeug.security's generate_password_hash, check_password_hash. But the same thing happens. Password from the database is different from what it is before being saved to the database. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For those who may be interested: I managed to make it work. The problem is with the __init__ function. When I initiate an instance of the User class above, the __init__ function already hash the password once. When I save it, the password is hashed again. Hence the problem. I solved it by removing the __init__ function. In the signup view, I first create an instance of the User class without the password field, then I assign the password to the newly created User instance before saving. That's how I solved it.

Comment: Same problem.Thanks a lot.You save me one day.